# Validation for invalid string value Mysql : '\xD9\xBE\xD8\xA7\xDA\xA9

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mariadb

I want to validate user input whether user is inserting invalid text or copy pasting invalid characters on textbox.

This exception usually occurs when user is inserting text from any other language.

I want regular expression or any other method to validate user input

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output:

Comment: @KKK if i enter some chinese like 你好 in the varchar textbox then this exception occurs or any other language

Comment: I don't believe you understand the actual problem, @Hishamshahid.  This doesn't mean the *user* provided an "invalid" value.  Arguably, it is impossible for this error to mean anything about what the user has provided.  This error means your application is not using correct character encoding when interacting with the database, and the *bytes* provided by your application to the database do not correspond to a valid *character* in the encoding your table uses.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i understand the problem my database has utf 8 encoding but i want to validate the error if user copy pastes any text from any other language than english i have to validate the text to give error to user.

Comment: @Hishamshahid this error is not related to other languages than English, and it is a naïve (<< see what I did there?) assumption that all English words will be error free.  If you are trying to avoid a condition you consider invalid, then do that separately.  The problem you appear to have here is a misconfiguration between your code and your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution the problem was when i was inserting text from any other language in varchar datatype from stored procedure it was giving above error but after i added charset utf8 with parameter in stored procedure like

```
IN spDescription VARCHAR(2048) CHARSET utf8
```

Then the exception is solved

Answer (score 1):

Here I have did some workaround.

```
select HEX('你好') REGEXP '^(..)*(E[4-9])' as x
Output
```

1   --It returns 1 as There is chinese character exists

```
select HEX('1234') REGEXP '^(..)*(E[4-9])' as x
Output
```

0   --Return "0" if there is no chiense character exists